# what is diffrent between get vs post vs put vs delete?

Tags: rest

i'm new in rest and confuse about http methods like get,post,put,delete,option,head
can any one please share me simple example.

here is my example:

```
@GET 
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getIt() {
        return "Hi there!";
    }

    @DELETE
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/getItDelTest")
    public String getItDelTest()
    {
        return "Hi there is getITDelTest method";
    }

    @HEAD
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/getItHeadTest")
    public String getItHeadTest()
    {
        return "Hi there is getITHeadTest method";
    }

    @PUT
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/getItPutTest")
    public String getItPutTest()
    {
        return "Hi there is getITPutTest method";
    }


    @POST
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/getItPost")
    public String getItPost()
    {
        return "Hi there is getItPost method";
    }
```

above this example i'm just create a simple method with diffrent-2 nature but i don't understand why we need all that if we able to do all these action with post

Comment: i think here is the ans that i exactly want [link](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2011/10/using_http_methods_in_rest)

Answer (score 6):

The [GET method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) is meant for data retrieval only and [should not have any side-effects](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1). But [POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) is meant for that specific purpose: altering data on the server side.

To change the state of a resource or to update it, use PUT and To remove or delete a resource, use DELETE..

Please read : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/

Answer (score 0):

The difference is based on the HTTP Action verb.  This verb is contained within the actual HTTP message.  The handling of these verbs is implementation specific.  For example in C# I can have 2 Web API methods named `Hello` in the same controller.  One could be mapped to the `GET` and the other to the `PUT` or `DELETE` etc....